# Is $ ‎\prod‎_{i \in I} K_i$ closed in $X = ‎\prod‎_{i \in I} X_i$?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X = ‎\prod‎_{i \in I} X_i$.Let $ (X, \tau )$ be a topological space and $K_i \subseteq X_i$be closed and $X_i$ be compact for each $i \in I$.
>
> Is  $ ‎\prod‎_{i \in I} K_i$  closed in $X = ‎\prod‎_{i \in I} X_i$?

Comment: This has nothing to do with compactness, it's the definition of the product topology. The product of cofinitely many closed sets is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use that each projection $\mathrm{pr}_i$ is continuous and that $\prod\limits_{i \in I} K_i = \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} \mathrm{pr}_i^{-1}(K_i)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in\prod_i X_i \bigm\\ \prod_i K_i$, then there is an $i$, such that $U_i := X_i \setminus K_i$ is non-empty. For $j \ne i$ let $U_j := X_j$. Then $\prod_j U_j$ is open, disjoint from $\prod_i K_i$ and contains $x$. So $\prod_i K_i$ is closed.

Comment: It’s not enough that $U_i\ne\varnothing$; you want $x_i\in U_i$.